# Матрица смежности неориентированного графа

Tags: c#

Надо сгенерировать матрицу смежности для неориентиованного графа, проблема в том, что не выполняется условие - `matrix[i][j] == matrix[j][i]` (то есть если существует ребро между `i` и `j`, то оно является и ребром из `i` в `j`, и ребром из `j` в `i`).

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int N = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int[,] matrix = new int[N, N];
            textBox.Clear();
            canvas1.Children.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    if (i==j)
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    matrix[i, j] = ran.Next(0, 2);
                    matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i];
                    textBox.Text += matrix[i, j].ToString();
                }
                textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы здесь две (с половиной).

Во-первых, вы для каждой ячейки считаете значение дважды. Например, ячейку `matrix[1, 2]` вы устанавливаете один раз вместе с парой индексов (1, 2), а второй раз — с парой индексов (2, 1).

Это не было бы особенной проблемой (ну, двойное вычисление, подумаешь!), если бы у вас был отделён контент от представления, и вы бы формировали представление на основе готовой модели (матрицы). Но вы записываете в представление элемент [1, 2] во время *первого* присвоения ему значения, а в элемент [2, 1] — во время *второго*.

Кроме того, у вас опечатка: `matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i];` затирает только что присвоенное значение, вы, очевидно, хотели присвоение в обратную сторону.

Поэтому правильное решение такое:

1. Отделите вычисление от UI.

   ```
   Random ran = new Random();
   int[,] BuildMatrix(int N)
   {
       int[,] matrix = new int[N, N];
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           matrix[i, i] = 0;
           for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
           {
               matrix[i, j] = ran.Next(0, 2);
               matrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j]; // обратный порядок индексов
           }
       }
       return matrix;
   }
   ```
2. В UI берите готовую матрицу и выводите.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Добавил вывод матрицы  вдруг кому пригодиться

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Random ran = new Random();
                int N = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                textBox.Clear();
                int[,] matrix = new int[N, N];
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    matrix[i, i] = 0;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = ran.Next(0, 2);
                        matrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j]; // обратный порядок индексов
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    for (int j =0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        textBox.Text += matrix[i,j].ToString();
                    }
                    textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                }
        }
    }
```